# Display Maximum rows Selector not working in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

I have created a dashboard in OBIEE 11g, the result have some 10k results but in my dashboard for performance purpose I have selected default 25 rows per page but when I click on Next Rows or display maximuk rows both are not working but if I export the analysis am able to see all the data, could you help me what could be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change it in instanceconfig.xml file.

Path should be like :

```
ORACLE_INSTANCE\config\OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent\coreapplication_obipsn
```

NOTE: take your files backup before changing it .

You ll see tags there :

```
 <MaxCells>10000</MaxCells>
    <MaxPagesToRollOutInDelivery>1000</MaxPagesToRollOutInDelivery>
    <MaxVisiblePages>1000</MaxVisiblePages>
    <MaxVisibleRows>500</MaxVisibleRows>
    <MaxVisibleSections>25</MaxVisibleSections>
    <DefaultRowsDisplayed>30</DefaultRowsDisplayed>
    <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>250</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>
    <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>65000</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>
```

You can change it according to your needs. After saved , restart your weblogic and opmnctl services  to make it available .